# Embedded QT5.12.3: QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called"

Tags: qt, embedded

Now I am trying to make the embedded `QT GUI` run on the `Ambarella CV25` board. I had cross-compiled the `QT 5.12.3` everywhere and compiled a simple `qt` example. The cross compiler is `Ambarella CV25 linaro-aarch64-2018.08-gcc8.2/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-xxx`.

When I download the `qt` lib and example to the board, I encountered the following issue:

```
./my_second_example -platform linuxfb
QIconvCodec::convertToUnicode: using Latin-1 for conversion, iconv_open failed
QIconvCodec::convertFromUnicode: using Latin-1 for conversion, iconv_open failed
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
QPainter::drawRects: Painter not active
debug paintEvent(): QPaintDevice  0x7fe05f0d78
debug paintEvent():  painter.isActive  false
debug paintEvent(): QPaintEngine  0x0
.....
```

Can anyone describe how to fix the issue? I searched the web, but all posts I found had either no answer to them, or give suggestion that paint under the `paintEvent` function.

My Code:
* `PaintTest.h`:

```
#ifndef PAINTTEST_H
#define PAINTTEST_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPainter>
class PaintTest : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
     explicit PaintTest(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
     void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
};
#endif // PAINTTEST_H
```

- `PaintTest.cpp`

```
#include "PaintTest.h"
#include <QLabel>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QDebug>

PaintTest::PaintTest(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{

}

void PaintTest::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
     QPainter painter(this);

     painter.begin(this);
     painter.setPen(Qt::gray);
     painter.setBrush(Qt::green);
     painter.drawRect(10, 20, 50, 50);
     //painter.drawText(rect(),Qt::AlignCenter,tr("Draganddropfile(s)here"));

     qDebug()<<"debug paintEvent(): QPaintDevice " << painter.device();
     qDebug()<<"debug paintEvent(): painter.isActive " << painter.isActive();
     qDebug()<<"debug paintEvent(): QPaintEngine " << painter.paintEngine();
     painter.end();
}
```

- `main.cpp`

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "PaintTest.h"

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
     QApplication a(argc, argv);

    PaintTest pt;
     pt.show();

     return a.exec();
}
```

And I will also provide the embedded `qt` configure parameters when I cross-compiled the `qt` everywhere:

```
../qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/configure -v -prefix /home/andy/Amb/cv2x_linux_sdk_2.5/workspace/build_qt/output -release -opensource -confirm-license -no-accessibility -make libs -xplatform linux-aarch64-gnu-g++ -optimized-qmake -pch -qt-zlib -no-opengl -no-sse2 -no-openssl -no-cups -no-glib -no-pkg-config -no-separate-debug-info -tslib -I/home/andy/Amb/cv2x_linux_sdk_2.5/ambarella/prebuild/third-party/armv8-a/tslib/include -L/home/andy/Amb/cv2x_linux_sdk_2.5/ambarella/prebuild/third-party/armv8-a/tslib/usr/lib -skip qtdeclarative
```

The `CV25` platform not support `opengl`, so I disable the `eglfs`, use the `linuxfb`.

Comment: Did you see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306391)?